# Simple PostgreSQL Self Join

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, self-join

This is what my `employee` table looks like where `manager_id` is Foreign Key to the same table it references to `employee_id` and indicates which employee has manager and who is.

```
 employee_id | first_name |  last_name  | manager_id
-------------+------------+-------------+------------
           1 | Windy      | Hays        |
           2 | Ava        | Christensen |          1
           3 | Hassan     | Conner      |          1
           4 | Anna       | Reeves      |          2
           5 | Sau        | Norman      |          2
           6 | Kelsie     | Hays        |          3
           7 | Tory       | Goff        |          3
           8 | Salley     | Lester      |          3
```

I did self left join and the result was what was expected.

```
SELECT
  e.first_name || ' ' || e.last_name AS employee,
  m.first_name || ' ' || m.last_name AS manager
FROM
  employee e
  LEFT JOIN employee m ON m.employee_id = e.manager_id;
```

```
    employee     |     manager
-----------------+-----------------
 Windy Hays      |
 Ava Christensen | Windy Hays
 Hassan Conner   | Windy Hays
 Anna Reeves     | Ava Christensen
 Sau Norman      | Ava Christensen
 Kelsie Hays     | Hassan Conner
 Tory Goff       | Hassan Conner
 Salley Lester   | Hassan Conner
(8 rows)
```

But this query gives me

```
SELECT
  e.first_name || ' ' || e.last_name AS employee,
  m.first_name || ' ' || m.last_name AS manager
FROM
  employee e
  LEFT JOIN employee m ON m.employee_id = e.manager_id;
WHERE m.employee_id IS NULL;
```

```
  employee  | manager
------------+---------
 Windy Hays |
(1 row)
```

So I don't understand why it returns something instead of nothing.**employee_id** will never be a NULL...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6e6af/9

Comment: Yeah it will. For Windy Hays you are doing `LEFT JOIN` on `e.manager_id` which is `NULL`.  Since it is `NULL` and there is no `m.employee_id` that matches it will  return `NULL` values for the m 'table'. Test for the `e.employee_id`. Run the fiddle withou the `WHERE` and returning `e.employee_id` and `m.employee_id` to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> employee_id will never be a NULL...

The `null` value comes from column `e.manager_id` (not column `m.employee_id` ) - that's Windy Hays, the top employee in hierarchical tree.

For this particular row, the `left join` that attempts to retrieve the corresponding manager does not find a match - so now `m.employee_id` is `null` in the resultset.

Maybe the `where` clause you wanted to write is:

```
WHERE e.employee_id IS NULL
```

... Which indeed will return no rows, as one would expect.

Comment: I didn't know that how the evaluation exactly works on joining...

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a `left join` from `e` to `m`.

When there is no match, then the `left join` still returns a row.  What are the values for `m` in the row?  They are `NULL`.

It is a convention that SQL uses `NULL` to mean "missing match in outer join" (but there is really no alternative value).

So, *all* columns for `m`m in the row for Wendy Hayes will be `NULL`.